# Card trade in python

Tags: python

I have a code that reads the card that I have to trade and the cards that I want and their respective quantities. But how could I read if I get all the cards that I wanted (in their quantity)?

```
# The trades
while True:
    trade = input()
    if trade == '---':
      break
    my_card, player_card = trade.split()
    if my_card in wanted_cards:
      if player_card in cards_to_trade:
        print("TRADED!")  
    else:
      print("NOT TRADED!")
      

# See if I have the cards that I wanted:
# ...
print("I GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!")
# ...
print("I DIDNT GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!")
```

Possible input:

```
1
CARD01 4
1
CARD02 3
CARD02 CARD01
CARD02 CARD01
CARD03 CARD02
CARD02 CARD01
CARD02 CARD01 #Here I would have 4 CARD02, but I only want 3, so I will accept this trade and then, trade the CARD02
CARD03 CARD02
---
```

Mine output (Wrong):

```
TRADED!
TRADED!
NOT TRADED!
TRADED!
TRADED!
NOT TRADED!
I GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED! #it prints the two possible outcomes because I don't know how to check which one is right
I DIDNT GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!
```

Correct output:

```
TRADED!
TRADED!
NOT TRADED!
TRADED!
TRADED!
TRADED! #traded because I know have 1 CARD02 more than I wanted, so it becomes a card that I want to trade
I GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save anything, you would need to save which trades you accepted.
So you need two lists, one with your current cards and one with the cards you want, tracking the changes to your current cards.

Then, at the end you can check whether you got all cards in the cards you wanted in your tracked list

Comment: I already have this two lists, but the problem is if the person that I intend to trade give me one card that I want but I already have the quantity that I wanted, I would trade to they and then this would became one card that I want to trade

Comment: Every time you trade a card and get something from wanted cards, you could put that card into a third list, which contains all cards you got and need. Then you remove this card from both other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Could you keep a count of the number of cards of each type and then use that to make your decisions?

This line seems to be the one that you need to update the logic of. I think you could do that with the dictionary that I mentioned originally.
`if my_card in wanted_cards:`

Replace that with a more complex condition that handles if you want more of the card.

```
# setting up your example, if I understand your example.
dict_cardcounts = dict()
dict_desiredcardcounts = dict()
list_cardnames = [f'CARD0{num}' for num in range(1, 4)]
for cardname in list_cardnames:
    dict_cardcounts[cardname] = 0
    # initialize all values to zero then overwrite the non-zero ones.
    dict_desiredcardcounts[cardname] = 0

# TODO: you need to get values into dict_desiredcardcounts

# The trades
while True:
    trade = input()
    if trade == '---':
      break
    my_card, player_card = trade.split()
    if dict_cardcounts[my_card] < dict_desiredcardcounts[my_card]:
      if player_card in cards_to_trade:
        dict_cardcounts[my_card] += 1

        print("TRADED!")  
    else:
      print("NOT TRADED!")
```

My original answer was here, but it was more the logic to determine if you were successful, maybe that wasn't what you were asking.

```
havealliwant = True
for cardname in dict_cardcounts.keys():
    if dict_cardcounts[cardname] < dict_desiredcardcounts[cardname]:
        havealliwant=False

if havealliwant:
    print("I GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!")
else:
    print("I DIDNT GOT EVERY CARD THAT I WANTED!")
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, so I have the quantities, the input is like "CARD02 3" because I want 3 CARD02

Comment: It returns this error: 

my_card, player_card = trade.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the input you selected not having a blank character that the split function is trying to split on. Therefore it only returns one object, but you define that you expect two things in this line: `my_card, player_card = trade.split()`

Comment: how could I get values into dict_desiredcardcounts?

Comment: You need to create it first, one way to do that is this:
```dict_cardcounts = dict()```

These are examples of setting and then updating the values inside the dict from the code in the answer.

```dict_cardcounts[cardname] = 0```

```dict_cardcounts[my_card] += 1```

It might be a good idea to google dictionaries.

https://realpython.com/python-dicts/ for examples walks through using them.